# How to set dependencies' features based on library features?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, serde

I have a package for which I want serde support to be optional. I have it set up as a feature, and some of my dependencies (e.g. nalgebra) have it set up as a feature as well.

In my `Cargo.toml` I have something like this:

```
[package]
name = "foo"

[features]
serde_support = []

[dependencies]
nalgebra = {version = "0.16.0", features = ["serde-serialize"]}
```

Is there a way to set things up so `serde-serialize` in `nalgebra` is only enabled when `serde_support` in `foo` is enabled?

Comment: TL;DR the duplicate: `serde_support = ["nalgebra/serde-serialize"]`